# Is it possible to hide a Google App Engine app from google searches?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I haven't been able to find an answer for this in the Google App Engine's documentation. In other words, would it be possible to "un-index" the app from Google search?

Comment: Yes, it should be possible by adding a meta tag to the pages your app serves. See: [Block search indexing with meta tags](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/93710?hl=en). Is this what you mean ?

Comment: Yes, that is one way of putting it! Thanks for the help =]

Answer (score 0):

You can add a robots.txt file to your domain with instructions not to index it. Google's bots respect robots.txt instructions.